# Can we deduce that the zeros of $g$ are also isolated?

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

Let $f:Ω→ℂ$ be a non-zero holomorphic function and $g:Ω→ℂ$ be a non-zero non-holomorphic function. We know that all the zeros of $f$ are isolated. Assume that $$f(s)=0⇒g(s)=0$$

Can we deduce that the zeros of $g$ are also isolated?

Comment: No, because you don't know anything about the zeroes of $g$ that are not zeroes of $f$. For instance, $g$ could be $f \cdot \mathrm{Re}(z)$.

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh: But the property is true for all the zeros of $g$ that are zeros of $f$.

Comment: But that's much too weak to tell you what you want. As a more extreme example, suppose $f$ is the constant function with value 1. Then your implication holds for _any_ $g$.

Comment: Not even the zeoroes of $g$ that are also zeroes of $f$ need be isolated zeroes of $g$. (And the zeroes of $f$ are also only isolated if $f\ne 0$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $f(z)=z$ and $g(z)=Re(z)$.